# Counting ordered selection with repeats allowed

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

You are given a sack containing $n$ red balls and $n$ blue balls. You take the balls out of the sack one by one and write down the sequence of reds and blues you get. How many sequences are possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: A sequence is completely determined by the position in it of the $n$ red balls: once you know where they are, you also know where the blue balls are. How many different sets of $n$ positions are there in a string of $2n$ positions?

Comment: I thought it was more difficult than it is.

Comment: @Herp: Combinatorics problems can be deceptive in either direction.